# Number converter with different bases

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to java and learning OOP and I have a project to make a number converter that can convert a value of any base  to decimal, or a decimal value to any base.

I've tested decimal to a different base and that's working fine for me, but the decimal to base [2, 8, whatever] isn't working. Any help?

```
public class NumberConverter
{
private int decimal;    // always stores the decimal equivalent, regardless of base
private int base;
private String strValue;

/** default set to base 10 w/ a value of 0 */
public NumberConverter()
{
    decimal = 0;
    base = 10;
    strValue="0";
}

/** base 10 value is used to set decimal, base and strValue
* note: toBaseX can do this for you also */
public NumberConverter(int value)
{
    decimal = value;
    base = 10;
    strValue = "" + value;
}

/** sets the strValue and base based on parameters
*        strValue is only stored in uppercase
*        decimal is set here as well provided newValue is valid */
public NumberConverter(int newValue, int newBase)
{
    decimal = 0;
    strValue = newValue + "";
    base = newBase;
}

//**** Accessor Methods ****//
public String getValue()
{
    return strValue;
}

public int getBase()
{
    return base;
}

public int getDecimal()
{
    return decimal;
}

/** sets the strValue and base based on parameters
*    decimal is set here as well, with a call to baseXToDec() */
public void setValue(String newValue, int newBase)
{
    strValue = newValue;
    base = newBase;
    if (isValid())
        decimal = baseXToDec();
    else
        decimal = 0;
}

public boolean isValid()
{
    boolean valid = true;
    for (int i=0; i<strValue.length()-1; i++)
    {
        if ((strValue.charAt(i)>47 && strValue.charAt(i)<58) || (strValue.charAt(i)>64 && strValue.charAt(i)<71))
            valid = true;
        else
            valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}

/** base of this object is set to x and strValue is the String value in base x
*   strValue is also returned, just for good measure
*   @param x the number base to convert to */
public String toBaseX(int x)
{
    String strResult = "", strRev;
    base = x;
    int div = decimal, mod;

    if (decimal == 0)
        return "0";

    while(div != 0)
    {
        mod = div % x;
        if (mod > 10)
            strResult += (char)(mod+55);
        else
            strResult += (char)(mod+48);
        div = div / x;
    }

    strRev = reverseString(strResult);
    strValue = strRev;
    return strRev;
}

/** take the currently stored strValue and calculate and return the decimal value */
public int baseXToDec()
{
    int exponent = strValue.length()-1;
    for (int i=0; i<strValue.length(); i++)
    {
        // update result
        decimal += (strValue.charAt(i) * Math.pow(base, exponent));

        // decrement exponent
        exponent--;
    }
    base = 10;
    strValue = "" + decimal;
    return decimal;
}

/** this is a helper method only
*        the integer value of digit is returned
*        -1 is the return value for an error
*   @param ch a valid digit for the given number base */
private int charToValue(char ch)
{
}

/** This is a helper method that returns strRev as a reversed version
*   @param strFwd the string to be reversed  */
private String reverseString(String strResult)
{
    String strRev = "";
    for ( int i = strResult.length() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
        strRev= strRev + strResult.charAt(i);
    return strRev;
}

/** a String with the current base and value is returned */
public String toString()
{
    String result = "In base " + getBase() + " the value is "+ getValue() + ".\n";
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: When you say it "isn't working", what exactly is going wrong?  And have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: What isn't working? You aren't obtaining the right result? Your IDE is throwing errors? Nothing is showing up? The code is nicely put, however throwing a large chunk of it doesn't quite help.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. It compiles but gives incorrect results e.g. converts the binary number 11 to 5680 in decimal

Comment: This line `decimal += (strValue.charAt(i) * Math.pow(base, exponent));` is wrong.  You should subtract `'0'` from the character, otherwise you're multiplying a number in the range of 48 to 57 or something like that, by the power of the base.  I won't post this as an answer, because there may be other bugs - but that one jumped out at me.  Also, your logic in the `isValid` method is wrong, but that shouldn't affect the result of the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those errors! I'll start there.

Comment: I suspect you're also starting at the wrong end of your number - you're treating the left-most digit as the least significant and the right-most digit as most significant, instead of the other way around.

Comment: OK, good luck.  If you manage to come up with a solution with all the bugs purged, could you please post it as an answer?  Then I will upvote it if it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strValue.charAt(i)` this is the problem: it returns a *character code* for the digit, not the integer value it represents. For example, the code for character '0' is 48 etc. You need to convert it into the actual integer value before you can use it like that.
One (non-portable, and frowned upon) way is to subtract 48 (or '0'),  as suggested in the comment. This relies on the fact that the digits in ASCII are coded sequentially, so 49 would be '1', 50 - '2' etc. It'll do what you want.

A (slightly) better way is `Character.getNumericValue(strValue.charAt(i))`.
It'll do the same thing behind the curtain, but will also work in exotic languages (like Indian, Easter Arabic etc.), that use different symbols for digits. Not that your little program will ever need that, just a good practice to adopt for the future.

Edit: same applies to isValid() function as well. Character.isDigit() is a better option thаn explicitly looking at character codes. You could also potentially simplify it by replacing the whole thing with `strValue.matches("\\d+");` (`\\d` is a regex code for "digit", so this returns true when your string contains only digits.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting getNumericValue- will take a look at that next, as you pointed out it's a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying re-invent the wheel here. Java already has pretty easy implementation.

Integer.toString(number, base) method will help you to convert to another base.

Example:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(10, 5));
```

Look Integer.parseInt() method also where ever needed.

Comment: This is for school so unfortunately I don't think my teacher would accept that, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You can copy the code from java source code http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Integer.java.html

Comment: If she's not allowed to use built in methods, I doubt copying the source code would be any more allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten around to isValid yet; subtracting the value of 0 as suggested and using a separate local variable did give me the correct output.

```
public int baseXToDec()
{
    int decVal = 0, exponent = strValue.length()-1;
    for (int i=0; i<strValue.length(); i++)
    {
        // update result
        decVal += ((strValue.charAt(i)-'0') * Math.pow(base, exponent));

        // decrement exponent
        exponent--;
    }
    base = 10;
    strValue = "" + decVal;
    decimal = decVal;
    return decimal;
}
```

Comment: Do not use Math.pow for integer operations. Write your own pow function for integers instead. You might suffer incorrect results due to IEEE floating point precision imperfection.

Answer (score 0):

Your method isValid contains true if the last char is valid and false if the last char is not valid.
Change it:

```
public boolean isValid()
{
    for (int i=0; i<strValue.length()-1; i++)
    {
        if (!((strValue.charAt(i)>47 && strValue.charAt(i)<58) || (strValue.charAt(i)>64 && strValue.charAt(i)<71)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```